# Usage of 对峙 in colloquial Chinese.

Tags: meaning, usage, colloquialisms

Since I have recently seen 对峙 used a few times in the Chinese shows that I watch, I decided to look it up and Baidu.com says it means"两山相对耸立" (two mountains standing and facing each other or at a stalemate) and I also used Jukuu.com and it said the meaning was "to face off". So I am wondering how do native Chinese speakers use this word because most examples of this word only talk about mountains facing each other and in the shows I watch they are usually not discussing mountains.

Comment: 对峙，隱含“比高度” 的意思。就是想競爭，一比高下。在戰場上就是想開火。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[对峙](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/10351/) means "confrontation; stand-off" (*be locked in a confrontation or face-off, with neither side attacking or retreating*)

It is a metaphor that means "two sides standing still like two mountains facing each other; neither one would back down nor could they advance."

> *So I am wondering how do native Chinese speakers use this word*

Some example:

两军**对峙**多日 - the two armies **stood-off** with each other for days (*对峙 as a verb*)

两军的**对峙**已经持续多日 - The **stand-off** between the two armies has been going on for several days (*对峙 as a noun*)

示威者与警方**对峙** - the demonstrators **stand-off** with the police (*对峙 as a verb*)

示威者与警方的**对峙**最后以暴力结束 - the **stand-off** between the demonstrators and the police ended in violence. (*对峙 as a noun*)

Answer (score 0):

it is a very formal and official word,we do not use it in daily life.its original meaning is two mountains facing each other,which you can se there is a 山 in 峙,but nowadays we use it to describe two force confront each other